# Получить координаты вершин многоугольника. Искажает координаты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Использовал пример из API по рисованию многоугольника и получения координат.
Это нарисованный многоугольник

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это полученные координаты: 
`[ [ [ 55.6825, 37.9151 ], [ 55.6825, 37.9153 ], [ 55.6830, 37.9152 ], [ 55.6830, 37.9157 ], [ 55.6831, 37.9157 ], [ 55.6831, 37.9152 ], [ 55.6830, 37.9152 ], [ 55.6830, 37.9151 ], [ 55.6829, 37.9151 ], [ 55.6829, 37.9150 ], [ 55.6825, 37.9151 ] ] ]`

А это результат вывода этих координат через Polygon:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить тот объект, который нарисован?

Comment: Видимо вы где-то округляете координаты, т.к. в примере который я нашёл округления нет https://jsfiddle.net/36rp9q7v/

Answer (score 1):

Полученные координаты обладают слишком низкой точностью.

Погрешность в 1/10000 градуса - это погрешность на местности в 11 метров (по меридиану), чего недостаточно для точного представления формы зданий, имеющих примерно такой порядок размера.

Как я вижу, геокодер [предоставляет](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/) 6 знаков после запятой - вот такие данные и нужны.